# Got an Error while run Geckodriver in python : [Errno 2] No such File or Directory: 'geckodriver.log'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-3.7, geckodriver

I'm building a Twitter bot using selenium geckodriver (version- 0.24.0- win64) in python. When I run the task in a terminal it gives the error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'geckodriver.log'.

I already downloaded and put the geckodriver in python folder

```
C:User/local/Appdata/programs/python/geckodriver
```

Also, this Geckodriver file is executable.

Comment: show your code trials and full error stacktrace

Comment: I can make new file in my working directory named "geckodriver.log" then it will launch the Firefox browser.